# c char pointer assignment

Tags: c, pointers, char, variable-assignment

I'm having problems with assigning a value to char pointers.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char line[200], *p, q;
    int i=0;
    FILE* f=fopen(argv[1], "r");
    for( ; ;){
            p=fgets(line, 200, f);
            if (p==NULL) break;
            printf("%s", p);
            i=0;
            while(p[i]!='\n'){
                    if (p[i]=='a') p[i]='A';
                    i++;
            }
            printf("%s", p);

    }
}
```

I know, that the line

```
p[i]='A';
```

does not work, but that is what I basically need to do, replace a `char*` with a `char`. `p` needs to be a `char*` because `fgets()` returns that. My question is if I can convert a `char*` to a `char` `[]` somehow, or if there is a way to assign a value to `char*`?

Comment: `p[i]='A'` should work (assuming that you expect it to set element i of a char array to 'A').  What problems are you seeing?

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? It looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: "I know, that the line `p[i]='A';` does not work" - it doesn't work in what sense? How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: `p[i] = 'A';` is fine. What exactly does not work? Note potential buffer overrun if a newline character was not read.

Comment: @simonc It does not change the value of p[i].

Comment: It should change the value of `p[i]`.  Daft question, does your input code include instances of 'a'?  Your posted code only changes the case of 'a' characters.

Comment: Can you please show the file you use for input? It _does_ contain at least one small `'a'` and a newline?

Comment: yes, it contains several new lines, as well as 'a'-s.

Comment: Were you expecting it to change the content of the file? That's the only line of thinking where I can get to that this doesn't work.

Comment: No, I was not, it prints everu line twice to the screen, with no changes. I have a small file, with short lines, s that can't be the problem either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works perfectly as is. Start with a basic case, given an input file such as:

> abcd

And 1 newline ("enter" key after the 'd') your program outputs to the console:

> abcd
> Abcd

Which is exactly how you coded it. It will *not* write `Abcd` back to the file, as you only opened the file for reading, not writing. Hopefully that's not what you were going for.

NOTE: if you do not have a newline in your file, or it's past 200 characters from the start you maybe seeing a buffer overrun which could cause this to look like it's not working. So again, start with a very basic file as I showed and make sure you code is *exactly* what you posted here.

---

> `> I know, that the line`p[i]='A'; does not work,

- Incorrect, you can use the pointer to the array `p` or the array itself `line` to access and change the elements. [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) stored the first 200 characters (or up until the first newline) into `line` and returned the pointer to it which you assigned to `p`, either will work to access or change the characters within the array.

> `> I ... need to ..., replace a char* with a char`

- That is not what you're doing here. You're using the `char *p` to access the array and change the `char` `'a'` for `'A'`

> `> p needs to be a char* because fgets() returns that.`

- Actually [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) gives you two things, it fills and "returns" your array (`line`) and it also returns a `char *` to your filled array. So no, you don't need to use `p` at all, below, the same code works without a pointer at all:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char line[200];
    int i=0;
    FILE* f=fopen("test.txt", "r");
    for( ; ;){
            if (fgets(line, 200, f)==NULL) break;
            printf("%s", line);
            i=0;
            while(line[i]!='\n'){
                    if (line[i]=='a') line[i]='A';
                    i++;
            }
            printf("%s", line);

    }
    return 0;
}
```